# Telegram bot webhook with self signed certificate is not working

Tags: php, cpanel, webhooks, self-signed, telegram-bot

I'm trying to set up a telegram bot the way documented here -  https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook.

I've tried nearly everything to use my own self-signed certificate but no success yet in making telegram call the URL I pass it even when it's returning a OK result

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

- I can call other methods successfully and they all work just fine.
- I used CPanel and openssl to generate a certificate and tried both of them.
- I used both a simple html form to call the `setWebhook` method and a PHP curl script
- I tried to pass the URL and IP address of my site
- I tested the webhook URL I pass several times and tried different simple script to trace any call to them
- I also checked all questions here like mine but none were solved

Is there something I haven't tried or thought about?

PS: buying a verified certificate is not an option for me, I already tried some free ssl providers like `startssl` (which they didn't accept my domain since it's ending with `.ir` with no sensible reason but should not be related here, right?).

Comment: did you try all of this https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed ?

Comment: @pengrad, all of them 5 times, but I'm already familiar with certs and I really don't think that's the problem. Somehow telegram has a problem with self-signed certificates. As a test I tried another host of mine with a verified cert and it just simply worked

Comment: @azerafati salam, rahe halli baraye moshkel peida kardid? man ham hamin moshkel ro daram , mamnoon misham agar komak konid. hi, do you find a solution, i have this problem too, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @darenshan, I ended up using `cloudflare`. It worked pretty well

Comment: @azerafati tnx alot, finally it worked with cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

In SelfSigned mode you should:

- Create your own certificate
- Set it to your `Domain` in `Hosting Settings`
- Send `public key file` of your certificate with setWebHook